# I want to disable the collect errors option in details of the chrome extension by default In menifest version 3

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I want to disable the collect errors option in details of the chrome extension by default

I am using menifest version 3

Comment: Open `chrome://extensions` page. Click `Details` for your extension. Change the option.

Comment: Please tell me why you want to know that.

Comment: I know how to do it from details but I want to close it by default.